# How to write loop in MySQL between two values?

Tags: mysql, database, loops, database-cursor

I have table:

**T1**

```
| Name | score |
| John |   1   |
|Anton |   2   | 
|George|   8   | 
|Peter |   1   | 
| Tom  |   2   |
```

I need to loop over table between two values.

I need to create a procedure or a function that for given value1 and value2 prints out (in alphabetical order) names that have in total(score) more than value1 and less than value2.

**EXAMPLE**

For value1= 5, and value2=12.

First i need to sort names alphabetically.

```
| Name | score |
|Anton |   2   | 
|George|   8   | 
| John |   1   |
|Piter |   1   | 
| Tom  |   2   |
```

Since value1 is 5, and value2 is 12, i need to loop until sum(score) will be more than 5, and less than 12. In this case result should be:

```
| Name | 
|Anton |   
|George|  
| John |
```

because in total they got more than 5 and less than 12 score.

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: my version is 8.0.27

Comment: Not sure of the logic here if only anton was in the raw data with a score of 12 there would be no output?

Comment: I think it should skip the Anton then, and go to next person.

Comment: Query should get first names which satisfy the condition

Comment: if antons score=12, output should be: George, John, Peter

Comment: 'I think it should skip the Anton then, and go to next person' - in my comment there is no next person

Comment: so in this case there will be no output

Comment: if antons score=12, output should be: George, John, Peter – then sorting by name is not logically correct

Comment: *In this case result should be* The result `'Anton', 'George'` (without `'John'`) matches "sum(score) will be more than 5, and less than 12" too.

Comment: What if `'George'`'s score is 12? What output you need in this case? Cumulative sum for `'Anton'` only is less then needed range whereas for each another row it is above the range.

Comment: it should skip anton and george

Comment: if anton=1, george=12, john =12, peter=12, tom=10, and value1=1 and value2=12 it should return only tom

Comment: but if anton=1, george=12, john =12, peter=12, tom=12, and value1=1 and value2=12 it should return nothing

Comment: Your task is absolutely unclear. Explain it in details. *Since value1 is 5, and value2 is 12, i need to loop until sum(score) will be more than 5, and less than 12.* - add intermediate values with this "sum(score)" which you want to filter by.

Answer (score 0):

1)discard scores > 12 2) workout cumulative sum 3) work out max cumulative sum in the required range 4) select those there cumulative sum is < max cumulative sum

```
DROP table if exists t;

create table t
( Name varchar(10), score int);
insert into t values
('Anton' ,   12),    
('George',   12),    
('John'  ,   1),   
('Piter' ,   1),    
('Tom'   ,   2),
('bilal' ,   5)
;   

with 
cte as
(select t.*,
         sum(score) over (order by name) cumsum
from t
where score < 12) ,
cte1 as
(select max(cumsum) maxcumsum from cte where cumsum < 12 and cumsum > 5),
cte2 as
(select  cte.*,cte1.maxcumsum
from cte
cross join cte1)

select * from cte2 
where maxcumsum > 5 and cumsum <= maxcumsum
order by name;

+-------+-------+--------+-----------+
| Name  | score | cumsum | maxcumsum |
+-------+-------+--------+-----------+
| bilal |     5 |      5 |         9 |
| John  |     1 |      6 |         9 |
| Piter |     1 |      7 |         9 |
| Tom   |     2 |      9 |         9 |
+-------+-------+--------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.022 sec)
```